# Edit file css in vaadin

Tags: css, vaadin

I want to edit the css file in the mytheme directory, but when saved, the file is not saved but automatically transferred to the old data. So I have to do. Please specify because I am a newbier. thank for all.

Comment: Have you read https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/themes/themes-creating.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there an scss file in the mytheme directory? If so you need to make changes there - the css is generated from the scss and will be overwritten.